# Unchecked Check-boxes are not fetched in array variable

Tags: php, html, checkboxlist

I want to get a string in **"000000"** this pattern of following array of check boxes respectively.

**checked = 1, Unchecked = 0**

**ex. "010101" , "100001"**

But **$_POST['check']** method only fetch **checked** check-boxes values and because of this I'am not getting the exact required pattern string that I want.

**Number of check-boxes may be vary.**

Please help me to get the exact pattern of **"000000"** string.

```
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]">

    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

$ary = $_POST['check'];
$str = '000000';
foreach ($ary as $key => $value)
{
    $str[$key] = $value? 1 : 0 ;
}
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign indices to the `check` and provide the value to each checkbox:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[0]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[1]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[2]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[3]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[4]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[5]" value="1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

So, in `test.php`:

```
$arr = str_split("000000");
echo join(array_replace($arr, $_POST['check']));
```

---

**Explanation:**

- [`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split) - Just to initialize an empty array with zero values
- [`array_replace`](http://php.net/array_replace) - Replace `0`s with the values you supplied in HTML checkbox
- [`join`](http://php.net/join) - Join the array to a string

**Update:** *Screenshot*

[image]

Comment: Sir, Thamilan:  Thanks for your answer but it produce string like "111000" even 1st 2nd and 6th checkbox is checked. It align all checked check-boxed to left and unchecked to right side of string which is not desired string output.

Comment: I think you are not using this exactly. It should work as it should be. I guess you have missed the index inside the `check` name - It should be `check[1]` not just `check[]`

Comment: See the screenshot

Comment: Sir, Thamilan: You are right I'm missing array indexes your code work correctly. I recommend this technique as best from all other I found yet thanks a lot.

Comment: Sir, Thamilan: isn't there any way to do it without index numbering?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constant to globalize the maximum number of checkboxes `$max = 6;`

Then, print your inputs with an explicit id:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <? for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[<?=$i;?>]">
    <? } ?>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then check if one is missing for negative values

```
$list = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
{
    $list[] = array_key_exists($i, $_POST['check']) ? '1' : '0';
}
echo implode($list);
```

**UPDATE**: Used Thamilan answer to improve mine.

---

**UPDATE** Added another way to read values

```
$list = array_fill(0, $max, 0);
// $list = array_replace($list, $_POST['check']);
$list = $_POST['check'] + $list;
ksort($list);
echo implode($list);
```

---

**UPDATE** This is even cleaner

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <? for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="check[<?=$i;?>]" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[<?=$i;?>]" value="1">
    <? } ?>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This already do as expected...

```
echo implode($_POST['check']);
```

Answer (score 0):

*[Adding this to answer [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812003/unchecked-check-boxes-are-not-fetched-in-array-variable/46812257?noredirect=1#comment80576890_46812257)]*

To do it without index numbering, atleast you need to specify the index in value:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="5">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

So your `test.php` can be:

```
$arr = str_split("000000");
$postValues = array_fill_keys($_POST['check'], 1);
echo join(array_replace($arr, $postValues));
```

---

In addition to this explanation, you add [`array_fill_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) to create an array with the given keys with specified value. So, your keys will be the ones that you checked in HTML and value is hard-coded to `1`.